# Three option for displaying dynamical javascript with css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Goal:
Value 1 show css > badge-primary
Value 2 show css > badge-secondary
The rest of the value show css > badge-danger

It take place at function handleChange.

Problem:
I was only enable to use false or true in order to use css. It is only two option.
The third option should be available and how should it be solved?  Any suggestoin?

Info:
*Newbie in reactjs

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-34tdvs?

---

css

```
h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.badge-primary {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

.badge-danger {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: red;
}

.badge-secondary {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgb(0, 204, 255);
}
```

---

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false,
      listData: [],
      list2Data: [],
      list3DataRaw: [],
      list3Data: [],
      value: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1')
      .then(response =>
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          listData: response.data
        })
      );

    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response =>
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        list2Data: response.data
      })
    );

    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(response =>
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        list3DataRaw: response.data
      })
    );
  }

  handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    // copy current list of Item
    const list = [...this.state.list3DataRaw];

    if (1 == target.value) {
      this.setState({
        value: false
      });
    }

    if (1 != target.value) {
      this.setState({
        value: true
      });
    }

    // filter out item being deleted
    const updateList = list.filter(item => item.userId == target.value);

    this.setState({
      list3Data: updateList
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { isLoaded } = this.state;

    const locations =
      this.state.list2Data &&
      this.state.list2Data.map(location => {
        return { value: location.id, label: location.name };
      });

    const locationss =
      this.state.list3Data &&
      this.state.list3Data.map(location => {
        return { value: location.userId, label: location.title };
      });

    //console.log(locations);
    //console.log(locationss);

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <select
            id="selectLocation"
            value={locations.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            {locations.map(({ value, label }, index) => (
              <option value={value}>{label}</option>
            ))}
          </select>

          <select
            id="selectLocationn"
            className={this.state.value ? 'badge-primary' : 'badge-danger'}
            value={locationss.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            {locationss.map(({ value, label }, index) => (
              <option value={value}>{label}</option>
            ))}
          </select>

          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.listData &&
                this.state.listData.map(item => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={item.id.toString()}>
                      <td>{item.id}</td>
                      <td>{item.name}</td>
                      <td>{item.email}</td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're using `1` and `!1`... but in your description you want to use `1`,`2`, and everything else. You need to change the `target.value` to support more than just `1`. Then you could do `if (target.value == 1) {} else if (target.value == 2) {} else {}`

Comment: I can see several conceptual problems in your code. I am trying to edit your code and I will try to explain the best what we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...........Another solution:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8aqbpa?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working branch,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dwtfr1

I will add comments in below code so you will know what I am doing.

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // Modified state a bit to remove getting the raw data. We can get what we need when we fetch data.
    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false,
      listData: [],
      list2Data: [],
      //Selected items needs to go in another state. I am selecting first item by default.
      selectedlist2DataItem: 1,
      selectedlist3DataItem: 1,
      list3Data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1')
      .then(response => {
        //You set state logic was wrong. You have to bring only state and update what's new. ...this.state, is for that.
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          isLoaded: true,
          listData: response.data
        });
      });

    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response =>
      //Set set state issue as above one
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        isLoaded: true,
        list2Data: response.data.map(location => {
          return { value: location.id, label: location.name };
        })
      })
    );

    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(response =>
      //Set set state issue as above one
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        isLoaded: true,
        // Moved the logic here
        list3Data: response.data.map(location => {
          return { value: location.userId, label: location.title };
        })
      })
    );
  }

  // We are handing 2 dropdown events so we need to know which is what. That's why I added name.
  handleChange = ({ target }, name) => {
    if (name === 'selectLocation') {
      // Selected item we need a number that's why +target.value. + makes a string to number.
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        selectedlist2DataItem: +target.value
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        selectedlist3DataItem: +target.value
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { isLoaded } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <select
            id="selectLocation"
            value={this.state.selectedlist2DataItem}
            onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, 'selectLocation')}
          >
            {/* maping is done on state value. value property is also using state. */}
            {this.state.list2Data.map(({ value, label }, index) => (
              <option value={value}>{label}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
          {/* Your class logic with values. use State for this pupose */}
          <select
            id="selectLocationn"
            className={
              this.state.selectedlist3DataItem === 1
                ? 'badge-primary'
                : this.state.selectedlist3DataItem === 2
                ? 'badge-secondary'
                : 'badge-danger'
            }
            value={this.state.selectedlist3DataItem}
            onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, 'selectLocationn')}
          >
            {/* maping is done on state value.value property is also using state.  */}
            {this.state.list3Data.map(({ value, label }, index) => (
              <option value={value}>{label}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.listData &&
                this.state.listData.map(item => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={item.id.toString()}>
                      <td>{item.id}</td>
                      <td>{item.name}</td>
                      <td>{item.email}</td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: The code doesn't work at https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dwtfr1

Comment: The second drop down changes colour. Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: I still can't see any changes in the font color when I have clicked on the name.'

Comment: There are multiple ids as 1s 2s and 3s in your API data. If you scroll all the way down you will see id 3 and more. If you select first few values Id is always 1. You won’t see any change.

Comment: I have uploaded the result I am getting. That's colour when you select an item with value="2"